# Converting Date to datetime.datetime in Python? Or vice-versa?

Tags: datetime, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-python-driver

**BACKGROUND:**

I've been trying to compare two dates in a database to see when records were last modified and if they should be updated again. I'm relatively new to using both Python 2.7 and Cassandra 3.0, and I haven't found any other answers for how to do this.

**PROBLEM**:

```
if(last_modified <= db_last_modified):
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to Date
```

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

```
#I'm getting the last_modified record in the database

last_modified = self.object.record.last_modified

db_last_modified = record_helper.get_last_modified_record()[0]['last_modified']

    print(type(last_modified)) # <type 'datetime.datetime'>
    print(type(db_last_modified)) # <class 'cassandra.util.Date'>        

    if(last_modified <= db_last_modified):
        print("Already processed newer or equivalent version.")
        logging.info("Already processed a newer version of the metadata. Please check your files and try again.")
        return
```

Comment: `db_last_modified.date()` will convert a `cassandra.util.Date` into a `datetime.date`.  Unfortunately you still can't compare that with a `datetime.datetime` because it lacks a time component.  You could also do `last_modified.date()` to turn that `datetime.datetime` into a `datetime.date`.  So your modified code would be `if last_modified.date() <= db_last_modified.date():`.  Note that this compares whole dates only.  Times are not considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

class 'cassandra.util.Date' have a function date(). It convert to datetime.date object.

so type(db_last_modified.date()) will be `<class 'datetime.date'>`

you will need to convert the datetime.datetime to datetime.date too. you can do it using date().

for example: datetime.datetime(2018,11,20).date()  ->  datetime.date(2018, 11, 20)

now you can compare them.

so change the line to `if(last_modified.date() <= db_last_modified.date()):`